# VPN server on Debian with login access from Windows

Tags: linux, debian, vpn

I have a friend in a closed country that needs a VPN. I want to install a secure VPN server on my dedicated server.

I have looked at PPTPD and OpenVPN, but I am not sure which one would be best? Or if there is a better solution?

He is using Windows and Android, So I want to be sure that he can use my VPN from those devices.

Which VPN server would you recommend, and do you have a complete guide on how to install it?

I have both tried installing PPTPD and OpenVPN, following the many guides I could find via Google. But even though they all seem very straightforward, it's not working for me.

Are there any easy-to-setup VPN servers out there? And maybe with a web interface or something like that to administrate it? The best solution would be without the use of certificates or ssh_keys since I then would need to create these for him or teach him how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing a PPTPD server, this seams to work from both Windows and android.

Following this howto: http://www.howtogeek.com/51237/setting-up-a-vpn-pptp-server-on-debian/

Cheers